# GCMLE NotFoundError: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am running a GCMLE experiment where I am trying to use `MirroredStrategy` to run distributed GPUs. The code works fine without distributed GPUs, and to make the change I adjusted my run_config to accept `train_distribute=tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(num_gpus=4)` and my config file to use a `complex_model_m_p100` machine thtaa should have 4 GPUs. I am getting a warning `Error reported to Coordinator: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`and then ultimately the job errors out with `NotFoundError: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` (see full stack trace below). At first glance this seems like an internal error where the proper libraries are not installed on the machines that I am trying to use. The responder to this github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22899) seems to suggest that "NCCL2" needs to be installed. Is there anything that I can do to get around this error or is it an issue with the GCMLE backend that is out of my control?

Stacktrace:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 368, in _batch_reduce
    value_destination_pairs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 182, in batch_reduce
    return self._batch_reduce(aggregation, value_destination_pairs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 524, in _batch_reduce
    [v[0] for v in value_destination_pairs])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 556, in _batch_all_reduce
    device_grad_packs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_utils.py", line 38, in aggregate_gradients_using_nccl
    agg_grads = nccl.all_sum(single_grads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 49, in all_sum
    return _apply_all_reduce('sum', tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 217, in _apply_all_reduce
    _validate_and_load_nccl_so()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 288, in _validate_and_load_nccl_so
    _maybe_load_nccl_ops_so()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 274, in _maybe_load_nccl_ops_so
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile('_nccl_ops.so'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
NotFoundError: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: We'll investigate...

Comment: Thanks! If helpful at all, I confirmed that I got the same error for `complex_model_m_gpu` so it was not restricted to the _p100

Comment: which version of TensorFlow were you using? We need to pre-install nccl in our training containers.

Comment: I was using runtime-version 1.10 (my understanding is that is the most recent since 1.11 was rolled back a couple weeks ago)

Comment: @GuoqingXu any updates?

Comment: The release will take ~one week. To unblock your work, I suggest you use our alpha feature custom container for now. Here is the alpha signup form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd62mhPwx4ty0u-K6HKZigV6H27DVmuZybRf3qzf81eNCuJ3g/viewform